# Batch search and replace file path

Tags: batch, linux-mint, path, sed

So I've got lots of m3u playlists created on my Windows machine inside a folder with file paths to tracks as:

`D:\path-of-mp3`

So first I want to replace all the `\` with `/` and then `D:` with `/media/etcetc` inside the playlist. How do I do that using sed or some other tool to every playlist in folder?

I'm on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -i".old" 's|\|/|g; s|^D:/|/media/etcetc/|' *.m3u
```